# Analog Microelectronics ASM 5915 pressure/temperature sensor coding problem

Tags: i2c, temperature, micropython, air-pressure

I'm trying to use an Analog Microelectronics ASM5915-1000-D pressure/temperature sensor with a Raspberry Pi Pico running CircuitPython. I'm communicating with the device using I2C, and getting data back. The data is 4 bytes, first two pressure, second two temperature. The documentation about how the data is structured reads like this:

> The last 6 bits of the first data byte and the 8 bits of the second
> byte always beginning with the most significant bit give the 14-bit
> pressure value. The 8 bits of the third byte and the first 3 bits of
> the fourth data byte give the 11-bit temperature.

**This quote [from this PDF file](https://www.analog-micro.com/products/pressure-sensors/board-mount-pressure-sensors/ams5915/ams5915-datasheet.pdf).**

**Written for Analog MicroElectronics**

The returned values are in mbar for pressure and celsius for temperature.

This is the C++ code the manufacturer supplies to get the data using an Arduino and I2C:

```
ReadFromWire(_address, _pressureMSB, _pressureLSB, _tempMSB, _tempLSB);
pressure = (((256 * (_pressureMSB & 0x3F) + _pressureLSB) - 1638.0) * (_pmax-_pmin) / 13107) + _pmin; //convert the pressure data into pressure in mbar, see AMS 5812 datasheet
temperature = (((256.0 * _tempMSB + _tempLSB) * 200.0) / 65536) - 50; //convert the temperature data into temperature in degree celsius
```

This looks okay to me, except I don't see how the temperature is being bit shifted correctly for the 3 bits of the last byte. Here is my CircuitPython code to get the data:

```
def get_pressure_and_temperature(self) -> tuple[int, int]:
    self.i2c.writeto_then_readfrom(self.address, bytes([]), self.buffer, in_end=4)
    pres_m, pres_l, temp_m, temp_l = unpack('BBBB', self.buffer)

    # we have to shift the pressure bits around to get a valid pressure value
    pressure_raw = (pres_m & 0x3F) << 8 | pres_l

    # we have to shift the temperature bits around to get a valid temperature value
    temperature_raw = (temp_m << 3) | temp_l >> 5

    pressure = ((pressure_raw - 1638.0) * (self.pmax - self.pmin) / 13107) + self.pmin
    temperature = ((temperature_raw * 200.0) / 65536) - 50
    return pressure, temperature
```

In my code I am shifting the 3 bits of byte 4 down. When I run this code I get what I think are reasonable pressure data; close to zero because nothing is connected to either of the input ports, so no differential pressure. However, I'm getting -57 degrees celsius for temperature. Since this is in my office, it's way off. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. If anyone has any suggestions, pointers, ideas, I'd greatly appreciate it.

Comment: writes_on - Hi, To comply with the SE [rule on referencing](/help/referencing) material copied or adapted from elsewhere, please add the name & link of the document you're quoting (from Analog Microelectronics??) describing the data format. TY

Comment: what are the four bytes that you get?

Comment: @SamGibson Thanks for the heads up about the copied material. I've edited my original post to comply.

Comment: @jsotola I'm typically getting four bytes that look like this:


00000110,  01011110,  01100000,  01000000

Answer (score 1):

The original code uses the 11 MSB bits as sent, whicy means it is a 16-bit value with 5 unused LSB bits so it is 32 times too large number and must divide by 65536.

If you shift away the 5 unused LSB bits, that already equals dividing by 32, and you end up having the 11-bit number, then you must divide by 2048, as explained in the chip data sheet.

Comment: I think that's what I'm doing, but will check again.

Comment: @writes_on No your code you posted divides by 65536.